# Text to Sign Language translation in Android

Tags: android

Does anyone knows of an Android text to sign language framework that I can use to develop an android apps to learn the basic sign language? The apps would allow users to input text or an audio (using the speech to text api) then translate the text into a sign language corresponding to the text entered.

Answer (score -1):

This should give you a start: [Text to Speech Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)